# Who will take strike for this particular situation, when striker is out Caught in the boundary?

Tags: rules, cricket, wicket

Today while we were playing, we had a following situation,

- Striker hits the ball and gets caught in the boundary
- Non-Striker crossed the center of the pitch  and the Striker too.
- Striker is out of his crease but has not crossed the center of the pitch.

We had these arguments about who will take strike:

- Two strikers must cross the center of the pitch for the non-striker to take 
  strike.
- Both batsmen must cross each other for the non-striker to take
  strike.
- Just non-striker need to cross the center for being striker before the catch.

Even after reading [Law 18.12](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-18-scoring-runs/), I am not clear on this situation. So, someone please clarify this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Laws of Cricket aren't always great at defining what certain terms used within the Laws mean, and I think "crossed" is one of those cases. However, we can use the definition in [Law 30.2 which does clearly define which ground belongs to which batsman](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-30-batsman-out-of-hisher-ground/):

> 30.2.1 If only one batsman is within a ground, it is his/her ground and will remain so even if he/she is later joined there by the other batsman.
>
> 30.2.2 If both batsmen are in the same ground and one of them subsequently leaves it, the ground belongs to the batsman who remains in it.
>
> 30.2.3 If there is no batsman in either ground, then each ground belongs to whichever batsman is nearer to it, or, if the batsmen are level, to whichever batsman was nearer to it immediately prior to their drawing level.

This then makes it easy to determine if the batsmen have crossed: if the ground belonging to the striker is at the non-striker's end, the batsmen have crossed. Therefore what is required is that:

- Both the striker and non-striker have left their ground
- The non-striker is closer to the striker's end than the striker

(There are some edge cases about batsmen running up and down the pitch multiple times before the catch is taken. I'm ignoring those here as they're somewhat unlikely).

Both those criteria are met in this case, so the non-striker would be on strike for the next ball (assuming it wasn't the end of the over of course!)

Answer (score 2):

*Center of the pitch is not of importance*, as both batsmen have crossed each other so non-striker will take strike for this particular case provided that the fair catch is not taken before they crossed each other.

---

From [Law 18 (Scoring Runs)](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-18-scoring-runs/): (emphasis mine)

> 18.12 Batsman returning to wicket he/she has left
>
> 18.12.1 When a batsman is dismissed in any of the ways in 18.12.1.1 to 18.12.1.3, **the not out batsman shall return to the wicket he/she has left but *only if the batsmen had not already crossed* at the instant of the incident causing the dismissal.**  If runs are to be disallowed, however, the not out batsman shall return to his/her original end.
>
> 18.12.1.1 Caught.
>
> 18.12.1.2 Obstructing the field.
>
> 18.12.1.3 Run out other than under Law 25.6.4 or 25.6.5 (Dismissal and conduct of a batsman and his/her runner).

And from [laws of cricket elearning Law 18](https://www.lords.org/learn-the-law/laws17-23/story_html5.html?lms=1):

> When a batsman is dismissed, the not out batsman shall return to his/her original end, except:
>
> - ....
> - When the striker is caught and they have crossed before the catch is complete.
> - ....

[image: rules]

Comment: But how do I determine if "both batsmen have crossed each other"? If they are level, have they crossed? What happens if the non-striker runs to the striker's end and passes the striker while the striker does not leave their ground?

Comment: @PhilipKendall Sir, I was just trying to answer as per specific situation of OP, your answer does explain all these question that you asked me so ++ for that.